# How to speed up Boost::Python::Extract when passing a list from python to a C++ vector

Tags: c++, python, performance, list, boost-python

I'm new to boost.python and have made a simple function for passing a list from python to a C++ vector:

```
void SetXValues(boost::python::list xl){
    int n = len((xl));
    xvals.resize(n);
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<n; i++){
    xvals[i] = boost::python::extract<double>((xl)[i]);
    }
}
```

xvals is an C++ STL vector. This function works and I can load the python list into C++ but it seems extremely slow.

A small speed test I did was to write a binning algorithm in C++ and in pure Python. The results show that the C++ method is only 5x faster when the time to pass the data from Python is included but of course the binning algorithm alone is considerably faster (74x).

So is there any way to improve the function above to make it more efficient?

Comment: why not `std::copy(boost::python::stl_input_iterator<double>(xl), boost::python::stl_input_iterator<double>(), xvals.begin());` ?

Comment: Brilliant! That more than halved the input time of the data to C++. I must admit though I don't quite understand what it all means, I guess I'll go look up the boost.python iterator documentation.

Comment: Could anyone explain why @ForEveR 's solution speeds up the OP's code?

Comment: @fireboot I'd imagine it's because `std::copy` copies a chunk of linear memory one time, while iterating through a vector copying each element is more costly.

Answer (score 1):

In performance critical parts, such as you describe. I usually avoid to store the data in a python `list` in the first place. A `list` is the correct data type to store arbitrary objects in it. In particular every object in the list can have a different type. But you already know that it will be a "list of doubles".

I would recommend to instead use `std::vector<double>` already in python. For that you would export `std::vector<double>` as a `class_`, lets call it `VectorOfDOubles`, using boost python. You can make it such that in python you won't see the difference between `list` and `VectorOfDoubles`, with the major difference beeing that you construct it like `xl = VectorOfDoubles(55)` instead of `xl = []`. You would need a little bit of work to get index-acees working, e.g. xl[5] = 4.5, but for this there exists the boost indexing suite, I recommend version 2, to help you.

Another alternative would be to use numpy ndarrays instead of `list`. There exists the boost numpy library that helps you to work with numpy ndarrays from boost python.

But as you say you are new to boost python, both boost numpy and boost indexing suite might be a bit hard. Maybe you first want to settle with making your own subclass of `std::vector<double>`, say `VectorOfDOubles`, and define `double get(int i)` and `void set(int i, double val)` and then export these two functions (together with size(), the constructor) to python. That requires some changes to your python code, but is easier for beginners.